# Patch/Override a .jsp file in /resources directory in OSGi bundles

Tags: jsp, osgi, osgi-fragment

Say I have a osgi bundle (xyz.jar) with multiple class files, jsp's, css files etc. I need to patch one .jsp file (say admin.jsp) in this bundle using osgi fragment bundle and/or require-bunlde.

What I have done is created a patch bundle with the patched version of the .jsp file only in the correct directory structure. To attach this the to the main bundle, I have created a fragment bundle to xyz.jar and marked the patch bundle as required (require-bundle).

Previously I have used this same method to patch a .class file in a osgi bundle. However it seems, the .jsp file doesn't get patched.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong here. Is there a better way to patch a single .jsp file residing inside an osgi bundle?

Comment: Why don't you just change xyz.jar to have the better jsp file?

Comment: "it seems, the .jsp file doesn't get patched". How do you know this?? What does your code look like, and how did it fail?

Comment: In OSGi, the unit of deployment is the bundle. I would strongly advise you not to try and hack around that. That creates more problems than it solves.